# Is there a meassure word missing in 在这河里游泳危险

Tags: grammar

In the next sentence is the meassure word 条 after 这 missing? I have seen the  phares on a hsk game page in the  internet.  在这河里游泳危险

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you break down "在这河里游泳危险" you can see a verb is missing.

> "Swimming in this river (is) dangerous"
>
> It should be either "在这河里游泳(有)危险" or "在这河里游泳(很)危险"

The classifier 条 is optional. when we are not counting the number of river. 这 (this) already indicated it is only one particular river

- "这河/ 这条河"  = "this river" - *You can omit the classifier 条 because there is no counting word*
- "这一条河" = "this one river" - *You cannot omit the classifier 条 and write "这一河" because there is a counting word 一 here*
- "这三条河" = "these three rivers" - *You cannot omit the classifier 条 and write "这三河" because there is a counting word 三 here*

Comment: when are you counting? can you say 这河很长?  can you omit when is only a single element o has it something to do when you use the grammar 在。。。里/上/下etc.  If not can you say 这电脑坏了?  Can you use it everytime is only one?

Comment: When you use determiner "这" (this) before a noun, classifier can be omitted.   "这电脑坏了" doesn't need  a classifier  because "this computer" already indicated it is only one particular computer. You know you are counter when there is a counting word like 一,  二, 三

Answer (score 0):

yes，you r right。And actually if you are using Chinese to communicate, you can ignore 条。

Comment: Then when can a measureword be omited?